# Specify Hive file location

Tags: import, hive, load, hdfs

I want to know is it possible in Hive to specify HDFS address for imported data?
For example I have files from three cities.I want to import related information of each city on a specific node.

```
City1 information on Node1
City2 information on Node2
City3 information on Node3
```

Answer (score 0):

HDFS does not really work that way: you do not specify which node to store data.

Answer (score 0):

As being a distributed file system, the files within HDFS can change location, specially if you think about ist ability to scale. You can determine the physical location of the directory, but not where the files are being processed.